# Achar XPath no Selenium

Tags: html, xml, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Estou quebrando a cabeça pra achar o XPath de uma `table`. Vocês poderiam me ajudar?

A estrutura é mais ou menos assim:

```
 <div> 
  <div id="divMF">
   <iframe name="Principal>
     <frameset id="frmset">
       <frame name="corpo">
         <form name = "frmConsulta">
           <div id ="estrutura">
             <div id = "menos50">
               <div id = "idtable">
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 5):

Se a sua ideia é chegar até o `<div id = "idtable">`, você pode chegar lá diretamente usando apenas isso:

```
//div[@id='idtable']
```

Comment: Se for XHTML pode ser até `//*[@id='idtable']` já que o id identifica o componente de forma unívoca.

Answer (score 1):

Na realidade eu precisei ir para os frames antes de ir pra div da table.
Ficou assim:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")));
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//frameset[@id='frmSet']/*")).get(2));
    WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("idTable"));
```

Valeu o pessoal que ajudou!